# load SQL and ignore duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I want to import an SQL file using PHPMyAdmin where I know duplicates exist.  I am using the syntax:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\Documents and Settings\...\db_settings_extends.sql' ignore;
```

I receive the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: I think you'll have to reveal that part of `db_settings_extends.sql` that has upset your RDBMS. Otherwise it's hard to guess the cause of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like duplicates are not the problem. It seems to not like your string value or something next to it.